# Can't release new version after create specific Track for Wear OS (Android)

Tags: android, wear-os, google-play-console, watchface

I have a Watch Face for Wear OS + Companion App for phone and tablet. I have created a new track specific for Wear OS, as suggested in:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13295490

But before creating the new track I have updated a new version in global track (Phone+Tablet+Wear OS). It's still not published, but the problem is that the new version is specific for Wear OS, and have been assigned to the phone version too.

Old version (global track, version 100 is Companion Phone App, version 1 is Watch Face):
[image: Old version]

Now Phone+Tablet track and Wear OS track are splitted. This is okay, but the AAB for Production (not Wear OS) is wrong:
[image: All versions]

The problem now is that I can't update the Production track to set the companion app again, even with bigger version code (20000003).
[image: Error updating]

I can't either delete the releases that are in "Full rollout" status, so I can't update the Companion App anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have the workaround:

1. Create a new release on Phone+Tablet track
2. Give a name for the update, but set no AAB and go next step
3. On `Staged roll-out` select 0.0001% targeting 0 users
4. Save and publish this release
5. Create the new release and update the Phone+Tablet track normally